# Likebox working but no feed

Tags: feed, facebook-likebox

Searching for days but can’t find the solution. I saw some stream questions but no solutions. 
On the [Like-Box Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) page testing the likebox with page: [TestPage](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Morgan-Isenia/119881441385718).

But no matter what I can’t make the to feed work. (IE and Chrome)
The feeds are new so that isn’t the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Like Box shows recent posts made by the page, all the recent posts there were made by a user account on the page's timeline, not by the page itself

Comment: Ok, is it possible to have posts made by a user account on the page’s timeline in the feed of the likebox? (And thnx for the quick feedback)